# Отобразить в Label название файла без формата

Tags: c#, winforms, label, richtextbox

Через `OpenFileDialog` добавляю текстовые файлы формата `.rtf` в `RichTextBox`. В данный момент использую код ниже. Но мне нужно отображать только имя файла, без формата, как это сделать?

```
label1.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;
```

Comment: ...учитесь пользоваться поиском. Класс `Path` вам в помощь. В данном случае нужен метод [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.SafeFileName)
```